# body type of physics objects in CBEffects

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision, particle-system

Is anybody aware of a way to determine the body type of the physics objects generated by vents in CBEffects (particle emitter for Corona SDK), since they cause a lot of collision detections, which messes up performance.

Thanks for your help. Greetings, Nils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using maskBits, which is fine.